# Problems with Ajax calls on a shared server

Tags: php, sql, ajax, mod-security

I've a web site with one particular page that has worked well for a few years but my host has recently moved me to a new server which is a shared platform. I don't understand the details of the differences between the old and new servers and the provider is not readily providing information.  Before I jump ship and find a new provider I thought I'd ask for any ideas as to how I might get the page working again.

The issue is that I'm using Ajax calls to populate and manage a folder hierarchy. The web page user clicks on a folder and it opens to show other folders or items. Absolutely straight forward and just the same as browsing folders and files on a PC. Depending on the type of folder or item the user has clicked on, further Ajax calls are used to retrieve information and images about that folder or item. As you can imagine, the rate at which Ajax calls are sent depends entirely on how quickly the user clicks around the page and very swiftly a tool called Mod Security decides it must be a bot doing all this clicking and the whole thing comes crashing down. It has worked fine on the old server but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it work again on a shared platform.

The reason I'm using Ajax calls is to fetch the information from an SQL DB and I wanted to keep this "server-side".

So, my question is whether or not there are any alternative approaches I can employ to request data from the  DB that might work in this situation? I've been looking around and am a bit baffled as, although I have been a software developer for many years, I'm not an experienced web developer. I thought web sockets might be ok but it seems these are also problematic on a shared platform. I could queue up the Ajax requests and dispense them at a controlled rate but this would likely make the user experience a bit of a bore. Alternatively, if there's a way to do the SQL client-side but restrict the access to the DB.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well we only have a description of your current approach but at a guess maybe the code could be refactored to do more in a single request rather than making lots of individual ones for small things

Comment: I interpret this question as "my hosting provider made a change and my site is no longer functioning correctly". I would work with the host because they caused the problem. If they don't work with you, that it a definite reason to jump ship. That said, when a host does this, they are probably also taking a moment to upgrade things, so I wouldn't be surprised if PHP was upgraded. I would turn on PHP and MySQL error reporting and see if anything is obvious.

Comment: Well… aDyson, the code could be refactored to cut down the number of ajax calls but there’s no escaping the fact that the user wants a response when clicking on a folder. Just how many clicks is too many? I had to tell my provider that the issue probably lay with mod security and it was a week before they worked it out themselves so my confidence with them is low. Support has been pants. However, Chris may be right and sit tight for a week or two as I can’t be the only person having such problems.

Comment: Trouble is I don't know the real frequency and number of (concurrent?) calls which is crossing the threshold, and there's no code samples so I was simply casting about in the dark a bit, thinking maybe you could make the "further Ajax calls are used to retrieve information and images about that folder or item" more efficient or something. You're asking about alternative approaches but since we don't really know precisely what you're doing right now it's hard to suggest anything meaningful.

Comment: Thanks ADyson.. I do appreciate your comments. The problem is that, in a perfect world, the speed of response needed is dictated by how quickly the user clicks. Max 2 or 3 times a second as they scan up and down the folder lists. I set up a test page with a single button that called an ajax function that did nothing. If I clicked on it quickly for 10-20 seconds , the thing locked up. I guess what I’m asking is if there’s any

Comment: Way of calling server side functions on a shared server that doesn’t cause issues with mod security if there are more than two or three requests per second

Comment: 2 or 3 times a second is way too much for any app, I imagine the host is worried you'll consume too many resources and make the server inaccessible for other customers' sites. There's got to be a better way of doing whatever causes that

Comment: Thanks ADyson. I can certainly rework the code to reduced the number and frequency of ajax calls. I'll just have to keep reducing them until mod security stops bitching about them and hope that the responsiveness is satisfactory for the users.

Comment: ModSecurity Core Rule Set _Developer on Duty_ here. Is this a fully managed solution? If so, you need to speak to your service provider and ask them to put appropriate exclusions in place to prevent ModSecurity from blocking your legitimate traffic.
Where are you seeing the term "ModSecurity"? Are you seeing ModSecurity error messages? If so, can you share them?

ModSecurity has the ability to perform basic DoS prevention by storing stateful information across multiple requests. It sounds like something like this may be in place. Without further information, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Hi Xanadu. My service provider moved my site to their new shared server which was the start of many problems including this one. Support has been generally slow and poor but they finally stated that, although the error log showed ModSecurity was blocking my ajax calls, they were not prepared or able to make any changes. I would need to go to a higher and more expensive level of service.

Comment: Their shared service is now targeted at standard CMS and not "custom" code. I wasn't aware of any of this when they swapped my server and there is no road back it seems.  ModSecurity could be configured to work but it seems this isn't permitted.  So, I have modified my simple page to do less Ajax calls and pushed all such calls through a simple timed queue. By moderating the rate of calls I can avoid the ModSecurity protection at the expense of a slower clunkier experience for the user. It's ok for now and buys me some time to think about moving to a different provide.